# GUI won't display two seperate scrollpanes

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

As you can see in my code, there are two scroll panes at the bottom. I need my gui to show both of these scroll panes on the right side, the smaller one(displaying the current amount of money the player has, this one I need to stay one line thick) and the second one, which will be constantly spitting out information of the player's rolls on the bottom.

Also how do I make it so that my combo box listener will give every item a 10 to its output to start out with then when it is being sent out it gives each 1 more so that they have their unique number starting at 11 then 12, 13, and so on.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class dicebot extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JComboBox combo;
    private JButton btnConfirm;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    dicebot frame = new dicebot();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public dicebot() {
        setTitle("Dice Bot");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0};
        gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

        //Every new Label however needs every part that says "user" or on the Password: "pass" changed to something unique.
        JLabel userTag = new JLabel("Username:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_userTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_userTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_userTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_userTag.gridx = 0;//Here are your x + y coords
        gbc_userTag.gridy = 0;//Adding to x moves left, adding to y moves down
        panel.add(userTag, gbc_userTag);

        //Every new textfield needs only the * part to change for it to be valid. (gbc_* =)
        textField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
        gbc_textField.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel startTag = new JLabel("Starting Bid:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_startTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_startTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_startTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_startTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_startTag.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(startTag, gbc_startTag);

        textField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldStartBid = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
        gbc_textField.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel multTag = new JLabel("Multiplier:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_multTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_multTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_multTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_multTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_multTag.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(multTag, gbc_multTag);

        textField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldMultiplier = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
        gbc_textField.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel minTag = new JLabel("Min Remaining:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_minTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_minTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_minTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_minTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_minTag.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(minTag, gbc_minTag);

        textField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldMinRemaining = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
        gbc_textField.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldPassword = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
        gbc_textField.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel passTag = new JLabel("Password:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_passTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_passTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_passTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_passTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_passTag.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(passTag, gbc_passTag);

        textField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldOdds = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
        gbc_textField.gridy = 5;
        panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel oddsTag = new JLabel("Odds %:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_oddsTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_oddsTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_oddsTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_oddsTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_oddsTag.gridy = 5;
        panel.add(oddsTag, gbc_oddsTag);

        textField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldMaxBet = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_textField.gridx = 1;
        gbc_textField.gridy = 6;
        panel.add(textField, gbc_textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        //This is the Combo Box
        combo = new JComboBox<String>(new String[]{"BTC","LTC","PPC","NMC","XPM","FTC","ANC","DOGE","NXT"});
        combo.addActionListener(this);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_list = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_list.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_list.gridx = 1;
        gbc_list.gridy = 7;
        panel.add(combo, gbc_list);

        JLabel maxTag = new JLabel("MaxBet:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_maxTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_maxTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_maxTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_maxTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_maxTag.gridy = 6;
        panel.add(maxTag, gbc_maxTag);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 5, 5));

        btnConfirm = new JButton("Turn Up");
    btnConfirm.addActionListener(this);
    panel_1.add(btnConfirm);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Current Balance");
        textArea.setColumns(1);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

    JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane();//This will hold the information the bot sends over such as win/loose or error
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JTextArea textAreal = new JTextArea("Input bot information here...");
        textArea.setColumns(20);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

        pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == combo) {
            System.out.println(combo.getSelectedIndex()+1);
        }else if (e.getSource() == btnConfirm){
            Dicebotcode dbc = new Dicebotcode();
            dbc.dbc();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things...

One, if you've added the same scroll pane twice...

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane();//This will hold the information the bot sends over such as win/loose or error
contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                          ^--- Note no "l"
```

And, even if you have added the two scroll pane instances, you've added them to the same place, `BorderLayout.CENTER`

`BorderLayout` only allows a single component to be added to one of the available positions it supports, so, in this case, only the second scroll pane would be visible

Comment: How do I make a second "center" layout portion... I'm not really good with that stuff and what about my second question on the output numbers?

Comment: Consider making another `JPanel`, set it's layout manager to use a `GridLayout`, add the scroll pane's to this and then add the panel to the `CENTER` position of the `contentPane`